# how to append a value to map[string][]string in arango using aql

Tags: arangodb

how to append a value to array of string using aql query

```
{
  "annotation_id": "1234",
  "text": {
    "june 2018": [
      "gain of revenue for this month"
    ]
  },
  "user_id": ""
}
```

this is my arango document:

```
for doc in annotation_info 
filter doc.annotation_id == '1234' 
update doc with {"text": {"june 2018":["test"]}} in annotation_info
```

i tried with above query but its overriding existing value but i need something like

```
{   "annotation_id": "1234",   "text": {
    "june 2018": [
      "gain of revenue for this month",
      "test"
    ]   },   "user_id": "" }
```

below is my excepted output for arango document

```
{
  "annotation_id": "1234",
  "text": {
    "june 2018": [
      "gain of revenue for this month",
      "test"
    ]
  },
  "user_id": ""
}
```

this is my excepted output i just need to append value test to june 2018 key with existing value can someone help me on this please 
this should be done within aql query

Comment: @stackoverflow we cant see your expected output

Answer (score 2):

To add to your June2018 array, you can use the push function:

```
for doc in annotation_info 
filter doc.annotation_id == '1234' 
update doc with {text: {june2018 :push(doc.text.june2018, 'test')}} in annotation_info
RETURN { before: OLD, after: NEW }
```

that returns:

```
[
  {
    "before": {
      "_key": "45740",
      "_id": "test5/45740",
      "_rev": "_Z-plp5S--_",
      "annotation_id": "1234",
      "text": {
        "june2018": [
          "gain of revenue for this month"
        ]
      },
      "user_id": ""
    },
    "after": {
      "_key": "45740",
      "_id": "test5/45740",
      "_rev": "_Z-pl0cu--_",
      "annotation_id": "1234",
      "text": {
        "june2018": [
          "gain of revenue for this month",
          "test"
        ]
      },
      "user_id": ""
    }
  }
]
```

where you can see that the expected change has taken place.

Note that I changed the column from 'june 2018' to 'june2018', which allowed me to remove all the quotation marks and make the query much cleaner to read (and write). In general, I do not like putting spaces or other special characters in column names as they serve no real purpose beyond forcing me put quotation marks all over the place.